# Proper mechanism to downgrade react-native

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, react-native

My situation is this :

I had a working copy of a react-native project that was working well. Had it commited to my git repository.

I decided to upgrade react-native to 0.26.3 and then 0.28 and finally ended up in a big dependency mess with collisions. So decided to go back to previous working version. Reverted the changes. Removed node_modules folder from my working directory.

But now `npm install` just won't work.

My working dependencies in package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "immutable": "^3.8.1",
    "key-mirror": "^1.0.1",
    "react": "^15.0.2",
    "react-native": "^0.26.0",
    "react-native-router-flux": "^3.26.1",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.5",
    "redux": "^3.5.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.1.0",
    "strformat": "0.0.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.10.4",
    "babel-jest": "^12.1.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "^1.9.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.9.0",
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "fetch-mock": "^4.5.4",
    "jest-cli": "^12.1.1",
    "mocha": "^2.5.3",
    "mockery": "^1.7.0",
    "nock": "^8.0.0",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.1.1",
    "sinon": "^1.17.4",
    "sinon-chai": "^2.8.0",
    "sinon-stub-promise": "^2.0.0"
  }
```

Now I get

```
npm ERR! peerinvalid The package react@15.1.0 does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer react-native@0.26.3 wants react@15.0.2
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer react-redux@4.4.5 wants react@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0-0
```

This just not makes sense to me, as my react dependency is 15.0.2 and react-native 0.26.0 as you can see in package.json.

Note that this is from a previous commit that was working (the whole lot).
I also did a `npm ls`. Weirdly wrong dependencies are shown in the tree like wrong versions of `react-native`, `react-native-router-flux`, `react`.

[link to ls output](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6bx509USYutVjdsS2NmNHEyNTg/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: can't you just revert your changes from source control?

Comment: I did. After reverting, I had to install `npm install` after reverting from source control

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please update your `react` dependency in package.json to explicitly be `15.0.2`, not `^15.0.2` since the latter resolves to `15.1.0` which causes this issue. It is recommended to leave it that way until you upgrade for the next time and get this error once again (to avoid `react` changing its version in the meantime and `react-native` not being ready for it).

Also, with npm3 `EPEERINVALID` is no longer an error, but warning.

Answer (score 29):

For existing projects if you want to install/downgrade to lower version

```
npm install react-native@x.x.x  ex: npm install react-native@0.43.4
```

This will install the version specified.

Check the installed version with `react-native --version`

Comment: How to downgrade properly not just project specific but globally? Is there a way?

Comment: This is just locally? How to do it globally?

Comment: check out [Upgrading react-native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/upgrading)   . may be helpful.

Answer (score 11):

### Update 2020

Just run

```
npm install react-native@0.43.8
```

Replace `0.43.8` with version you need.

Answer (score 5):

Downgrading React Native requires manual steps.  I recommend using https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/ and here are my steps

1. Set your current version as base and select the previous minor version of react-native
2. Revert all the changes made to files as displayed in the compare view in step 1
3. Delete node_modules folder, clear watchman, reset metro cache, delete pods, clear ios and android cached files. `npx react-native-clean-project` is super helpful.
4. `yarn` or `npm install` and reinstall pods for ios
5. Make sure all your jest tests, detox tests and manually testing both iOS and Android are working as expected.
6. (if needed) Repeat the steps to downgrade to another lower version

Suggestion: If you're downgrading multiple minor versions then it might be easier to downgrade one version at a time. For example, downgrading from 0.61.x to 0.58.x, would be less work to downgrade to version 0.60.x first, test and make sure everything works in iOS and Android then move on

Comment: Thanks for this. Do you know if it's necessary to update project.pbxproj by hand? Or does updating all the other files cause project.pbxproj to get updated automatically?

Comment: @gkeenley You have to update project.pbxproj by hand unfortunately

Comment: Ok thanks. Do you know generally what type of changes cause project.pbxproj to update automatically, and which ones don't?

Comment: The things that I know are: using Xcode and applying their recommended updates. using react-native upgrade or any command line tools that help upgrading react-native projects.

Comment: Those are the ones that do update it automatically?

Comment: As far as I know, yes.

Comment: Sorry I thought I had. Done now :)

Answer (score 2):

Try `npm prune` and then `npm i` again.

The command `npm prune` will basically remove all unwanted packages, and `npm i` will make sure all missing packages are installed.

Comment: please let me know if this does not fix your problem

Comment: Hi, No it did not solve the problem. I also did `rm -rf ~/.npm`, `npm cache clear`. Absolutely nothing helps.

Comment: can you please delete entire project from local.. pull it back and do fresh npm i.. logically does not make sense but you never know it might fix your problem

Comment: Tried that as well in vain. Am not sure what else is there to do.

Comment: Try to checkout few commits prior to upgrade

Comment: thats precisely what I did and didnt work.I have raised a request with npm. Hopwfull some npm expert will help me out

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115570/discussion-between-sathyakumar-seshachalam-and-rohit-shedage).

Answer (score 1):

I tried to downgrade from `react-native 0.71.1` to `0.70.4` with just `npm i react-native@0.70.4` and fix whatever errors came up. In my case I needed this because the package `react-native-vision-camera` was not yet compatible with react-native 0.71.1.

But I had dozens of errors, which after a while I started to understand are due to the fact that **the whole android folder that is being set up from a template when you run the `npx react-native init` script, has differences and must match the react-native package version.** So I guess if you downgrade a minor version in this way, not just a patch, you are just very lucky if it works somehow. I would not do it.

I instead decided to freshly init react-native with the desired version:

- Just git commit all your changes and push them to the remote (to be safe), `mv` your current project folder to a different name.
- Run `npx react-native init <YourProjectName> --version 0.70.6` to get the desired version, but make sure to use the same ProjectName, otherwise you might have configuration mismatches.
- Integrate your own code from the old project folder (if you forget something git will tell you later), merge configuration files, etc.
- add packages by running `npm install <package-name> <package-2-name> <etc.)` and `npm install -D` (for devDependencies). Don't copy the dependencies / devDependencies over from package.json, as that way you'll probably not get the right package versions that match your versions of react, react-native etc.
- finally copy `.git` folder from your old project folder into the new one, and check the changes, to make sure you did not forget anything. **And then you will actually see all the differences in the template I mentioned above. In my case more than 30 files were different between those minor versions.**

Answer (score 0):

If you're using react-native you can modify your package.json file with the versions that you need and then delete all your node modules rm -rf node_modules and then reinstall npm install

Comment: This is not a recommended method

Answer (score 0):

If you change the version in `Package.json` and reinstall `npm packages` it will make **build errors**. Please [refer](https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/) and **downgrade/upgrade** to a **specific** version.

Comment: there is no build errors for me after downgrading, but the app crashes when it's run, it's blocked on a black screen.