# Need help in compilation of react-native iOS app

Tags: react-native

I am relatively new to react-native and trying to compile a previously running project but not able to compile

I am facing this error while compiling the code.

** BUILD FAILED **

Installing build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/myapp.app
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=2):
Failed to install the requested application
An application bundle was not found at the provided path.
Provide a valid path to the desired application bundle.
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/myapp.app/Info.plist
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

I have tried all solutions mentioned below
[Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37461703/print-entry-cfbundleidentifier-does-not-exist)

this is my package.json file

```
{
    "name": "myapp",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "devDependencies": {
        "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^3.1.1",
        "babel-preset-react-native-stage-0": "^1.0.1",
        "babel-root-slash-import": "^1.1.0",
        "eslint-import-resolver-babel-module": "^4.0.0",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.11.0",
        "jest-react-native": "^18.0.0",
        "jetifier": "^1.6.3",
        "prop-types": "^15.6.1",
        "react-native-dotenv": "^0.1.1",
        "react-test-renderer": "16.2.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "react-native start",
        "android": "react-native run-android",
        "ios": "react-native run-ios",
        "test": "node node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js",
        "clean": "react-native-clean-project"
    },
    "jest": {
        "preset": "react-native"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "moment": "^2.22.0",
        "react": "16.2.0",
        "react-native": "0.52",
        "react-native-clean-project": "^1.0.8",
        "react-native-device-info": "^0.21.5",
        "react-native-document-picker": "^2.1.0",
        "react-native-firebase": "^4.2.0",
        "react-native-htmlview": "^0.12.1",
        "react-native-image-picker": "^0.26.7",
        "react-native-mime-types": "^2.2.1",
        "react-native-network-info": "^3.2.2",
        "react-native-pdf": "^4.0.0",
        "react-native-photo-view": "^1.5.2",
        "react-native-push-notification-ce": "^3.1.3",
        "react-native-swiper": "^1.5.13",
        "react-native-video": "^2.3.1",
        "react-native-video-preview": 
 "git://github.com/chadsmith/react-native-video-preview.git",
        "react-native-video-processing": "^1.13.0",
        "react-navigation": "^1.5.8",
        "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.10.12"
    }
}
```

Comment: do you try this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49298841/react-native-ios-build-cfbundleidentifier-does-not-exist .

Answer (score 2):

Try cleaning up the build folder and deleting DerivedData folder which clears the build cache. But the main reason is that you haven't set the bundle ID for the app. Assuming you followed the link and made sure that you have one, then usually the build being cached is the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are 2 possible causes:

**1) At some point there is some other error that is blocking the creation of the JS bundle.**

Check the entire log of the build attempt carefully.

**2) The bundle is generated at the incorrect path or using the incorrect `index.js` file.**

More info here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/57604941/1979861