# React native fresh project error

Tags: react-native

Last few days ago something got updated on `react-native`. I don't know what?
Now the default code which created when we create a new project on `react-native` is not running.

Last week I created a new fresh project on react native using `react-native init Projectname` Command.

It creates a project with default code of welcome screen and we expect a output screen

[image: welcome screen in react-native]

but it gives an error

[image: Error message screen]

Why?

Comment: which version of react native are you using? and which os? windows 10?

Comment: React-native: 0.56.0
React-native-cli: 2.0.1
Os: windows 10

Comment: it looks like an issue from react end. you can find more details here https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/19953 .one quick solution is to downgrade to version .55

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like an issue from the React end itself. Lot of people raised this issue in their github and see that [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/19953). So until this get resolved, its better not to upgrade to 0.56 . Track this ticket for latest updates. You can try downgrade it to 0.55 and see whether the issue got fixed. For downgrade find the details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38024203/proper-mechanism-to-downgrade-react-native)

Comment: I downgrade react-native version to 0.55.0 but error is still there.

Comment: It's mentioned on the ticket itself, for some of them only downgrading worked. So create a new project with .55 version specific and see whether it's working

Answer (score 0):

Create a project with older version.

react-native init --version="react-native@version" project_name

Example:- react-native init --version="react-native@0.55.0" myapp.

Answer (score 0):

**Follow these Steps**

1- Open terminal, cd yourProject

2- execute `npm ls`

3- if some packages emphasized Red, note down

4- open finder, press `CMD + SHIFT + G`, write your project path and go !

5- open node modules, delete Packages that you wrote down

6- back to terminal, execute `npm install`

**Thats ALl !**