# CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "ReactCommon/callinvoker"

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods, expo

I've taken several steps to resolve this issue, including deleting `node_modules`, deleting `pod.lock`, ran `yarn cache clean`, ran `npx react-native-clean-project`, ran `pod install --repo-update` ... but nothing so far has worked. This is for an Expo bare workflow project.

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "ReactCommon/callinvoker":
  In Podfile:
    ReactCommon/callinvoker (from `../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon`)

None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: `ReactCommon/callinvoker (from `../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon`)`.

You have either:
 * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
 * mistyped the name or version.
 * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.
```

Comment: I just ran into this as well. Hoping someone has some insight.

Answer (score 1):

open `podfile` in ios folder

and replace

```
pod 'ReactCommon/callinvoker', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"
pod 'ReactCommon/turbomodule/core', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"
```

to

```
pod 'React-callinvoker', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/callinvoker"
pod 'ReactCommon/turbomodule/core', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"
```

Answer (score 0):

I downgraded from `react-native 0.63.3` to `react-native 0.62.2`, and that solved my cocoa pods issue.

To downgrade react-native use either of the following commands depending on your package manager.

`npm install react-native@x.x.x` or `yarn add react-native@x.x.x`

For more information on how to downgrade react-native check out the link below and hopefully it helps!

[Proper mechanism to downgrade react-native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38024203/proper-mechanism-to-downgrade-react-native#43751324)

Answer (score 0):

open podfile in ios folder

and replace
pod 'React-callinvoker', :path => "#{rnPrefix}/ReactCommon"

to

pod 'React-callinvoker', :path => "#{rnPrefix}/ReactCommon/callinvoker"