# Is there a way to downgrade React-Native?

Tags: react-native, expo, downgrade

I have react-native version 0.69.0, but Expo SDK 45 only works with react-native 0.68.2. Is there a way to downgrade my project to this version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this stackoverflow question by 'Sathyakumar Seshachalam' may help you.

**link**: [Proper mechanism to downgrade react-native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38024203/proper-mechanism-to-downgrade-react-native)

Answer from chetan and liamnickell:

For existing projects if you want to install/downgrade to lower version

```
npm install react-native@a.b.c
```

This will install the version specified.

Check the installed version with react-native --version